# Devise, how to use with MongoDB's embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongoid, warden

In my Rails app I have to models: Account & User. I'm using MongoID and Devise with Omniauth.

I'm having some issues with devise and warden about logging in users correctly with this configuration:

```
class Account
  #code..
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :users
  #code..
end

class User
  #code..
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:twitter] #just an example.. 

  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :account
  #code..
end
```

And a pretty standard OmniauthCallbacksController:

```
 class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

   def twitter
     callback_of('Twitter')
   end

   protected

   def callback_of(provider)
     @user = User.find_user_from(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
     @user = User.new_with(request.env["omniauth.auth"]) if @user.blank?

     if @user.persisted?
       sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
       set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider) if is_navigational_format?
     else
       redirect_to new_user_registration_path, alert: "There was a problem with your #{provider} account. Please try again."
     end
   end

   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     if resource.registered
       account_path(resource.account)
     else
       new_account_path
     end
   end
end
```

That code works great, if the user is not registered an account document is created and an embedded user document is stored inside it. Then it's called `sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication` and the user is correctly signed in. Then there is a redirection to `new_account_path` where things become weird..

After redirection user is not logged in anymore, and therefore all devise helpers, like `current_user` are useless. I guess this is caused because users are embedded on accounts so Warden can't find the user correctly.

I found this Devise wiki's [post](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Embed-users-in-your-account-model-with-Mongoid), but seems to be outdated.

I'm not a devise/warden expert, so I'd need some help with this. Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I had to overwrite the current_user method in ApplicationController, accessing directly the Warden session.. I didn't find a better way to do it.. here a [gist](https://gist.github.com/bismark64/c9bb4bc734f8a5b1e4de)